# node.js: consume promises using await

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, promise, async-await

I have the following code that consumes a soap web service:

```js
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso?WSDL';
var args = { ubiNum: '1234' };

soap.createClientAsync(url).then((client) => {
  return client.NumberToWordsAsync(args);
}).then((result) => {
  console.log(result[0].NumberToWordsResult)
});
```

And I'm trying to rewrite it using await, this is my attempt at doing it:

```js
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso?WSDL';
var args = { ubiNum: '1234' };

var client = await soap.createClientAsync(url);
var result = await client.NumberToWordsAsync(args);
console.log(result[0].NumberToWordsResult)
```

But I get the following error:

```
var client = await soap.createClientAsync(url);
             ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

What am I missing?

BTW: here's a [repl](https://repl.it/@opensas/BasicNodeSoapClientWithPromises) in case anyone wants to play with it: https://repl.it/@opensas/BasicNodeSoapClientWithPromises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

await will works only inside async functions. You can't put await statements other than async functions. So you can rewrite ur code such as,

```
(async function() {
  var soap = require('soap');
  var url = 'http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso?WSDL';
  var args = { ubiNum: '1234' };

  var client = await soap.createClientAsync(url);
  var result = await client.NumberToWordsAsync(args);
  console.log(result[0].NumberToWordsResult);
})();
```